# Unable to upload csv dataset correctly on keras DNN

Tags: python, numpy, csv, keras, deep-learning

I am using the [Kaggle dataset][1] for mnist sign language. There are 785 columns in total including the one column with the labels for CSV dataset. Also is it a good idea to use CSV for images rather than real images

The following code is running fine until mode.fit() gives an error

````
"""CSV_MODEL.ipynb

Automatically generated by Collaboratory.

The original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u8GDJe-sWtz12YO7YusClJR9UeDJ852Y
"""

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(23)

import csv
import numpy
filename = 'sign_mnist_train.csv'
raw_data = open(filename, 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(raw_data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
x = list(reader)
data = numpy.array(x).astype('float')
print(data.shape)

print(data.shape[1])
X = data[:,0:784]
Y = data[:,784]

print(X.shape[1])
print(X)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512,input_dim = 784,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(24,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X,Y,epochs=100,batch_size=20)```
````

and it gives an error like this

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_34 to have shape (24,) but got array with shape (1,)
[1]: https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

> loss='categorical_crossentropy'

you have to encode label first(one hot encoding) by use

> keras.utils.to_categorical(Y)

or you can change your loss function to

> loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy '